# Re-use binaries created when checking a PR after rebasing it

Tags: github-actions

I have a repository where the main branch should create a *snapshot* release each time new commits are pushed. I can do this with a workflow. The snapshot will be hosted outside of GitHub since GitHub releases don't seem to support the concept of a snapshot.

This repository also has a workflow that runs on PRs and checks if they build. This workflow, as side effect, creates all the content of a snapshot. Since building takes some time, I want to avoid doing it twice and want to re-use the result of the PR check for creating the snapshot when the PR is merged.

Caches seem to be the solution for this problem: the PR check would create a cache identified by its commit ID, and then after merging, I can retrieve that cache. However, we merge PRs via "Rebase & Merge". Thus, the *merge commit* that will be fetched by `actions/checkout` does not have the same ID as the result of integrating the PR would have.

How can I solve this? Can I tell `actions/checkout` to check out the *rebased* commit? That commit doesn't exist yet, but neither does the merge commit and GitHub is still able to check it out.

Comment: Minor hint: GitHub releases support the concept of a pre-release; see https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/releases as an example (the repository is maintained by me with contributors).

Comment: @phd I don't think that matches onto our use-case. We need snapshots so that our other repositories can always build against the latest commit (without the need to build it). If we pushed this to GitHub, it would be a single eternal pre-release with changing assets.

Comment: That's surely up to you.

Comment: I would avoid this approach as it might produce inconsistent results. You mention the PR is being `rebased and merged`. This means the `HEAD` of the branch/PR would become different once you merge it. As result you could end in situations where you would need `binary-Merged`, but you used `cached-binary-PR` and therefore have incompatibilities or inconsistencies.

Comment: It sounds like a use case for artifacts to me, rather than caches.

Comment: @tftd This is exactly why I want to do the check on the rebased commit. GitHub does check whether the PR can be rebased and my hope is that this already generates the rebased commit internally and I can somehow access it.

Comment: @BenjaminW. All docs I found said that artifacts cannot be shared between workflows. I have two different workflow, one is the check for the PR, the other is the snapshot builder for the main branch. They cannot be merged into one.

Comment: There's a [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/artifacts?apiVersion=2022-11-28) that lets you share between workflows.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Fair enough. But I would have the same problem, wouldn't I? I'd need to identify the artifact from the PR in the workflow for main branch pushes.

Comment: You could use the Git tree hash to determine if it's based on the same code.

Comment: @BenjaminW. That seems to be the answer I'm looking for. I'm not sure how to use the tree hash as cache ID since it doesn't seem to be part of the webhook payload I get for the `pull_request` event. Could you write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea to tackle this problem, as Benjamin W. pointed out, is to use the tree hash instead of the commit hash to identify the binaries. The tree hash will be the same after rebasing, since the files stay the same.

The problem with GitHub's facilities is, they are not designed for this use-case:

- Artifacts are not designed to be used between workflows. There is a REST API to still do that, but it's quite complicated and requires you to identify the workflow that created the artifact.
- Similarly, Caches cannot be used. While they *are* designed to be shared between workflows, they do have a scope. For example, a cache of the main branch can be used by all other branches, but not vice-versa. In this case, a cache created by a pull request cannot be used in the main branch.

I did eventually opt to store my caches on my own server. The GitHub action workflows now look like this:

#### PR workflow

```yaml
name: Check Pull Request
on: pull_request
jobs:
  build:
    name: Check Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Calculate Cache Hash
        id: cache-hash
        run: |
          echo "tree=$(git rev-parse HEAD:)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - name: Build
        run: |
          # build instructions here
          # assume the result of this is put in the directory `build-result`
      - name: Create Cache
        run: |
          tar cf - build-result | zstd -o ${{ steps.cache-hash.outputs.tree }}.tar.zst
          # now upload the .tar.zst file somewhere
          # this is left out since the details don't matter;
          # the important thing is that you can later query it by its tree hash
```

### Push workflow

```yaml
name: Create Snapshot
on: { push: { branches: [ develop ] } }
jobs:
  create-snapshot:
    name: Create Snapshot
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Calculate Cache Hash
        id: cache-hash
        run: |
          echo "tree=$(git rev-parse HEAD:)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - name: Restore Cache
        run: |
          # fetch your cache here. you should do this by querying
          # the tree hash ${{ steps.cache-hash.outputs.tree }}.
          
          # after fetching, you extract it:
          unzstd -c ${{ steps.cache-hash.outputs.tree }}.tar.zst | tar xf -
      - name: Create Snapshot
        run: |
          # maybe tar it again, upload it somewhere
```

This is somewhat simplified; you will also need instructions to build it again in the push workflow if the tree hash has changed (e.g. if someone else pushed to develop after you created the pull request but before you merged it).

Comment: There's an alternative syntax that's a bit more self-documenting, `git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}`.